# I am a beginner coder and i'm trying to code a tic-tac-toe game but i'm getting errors i dont understand

Tags: java, compiler-errors, dereference

The errors I'm getting are "cannot find symbol." on the period after "tic"
      p1L = tic.nextChar();

, and "cannot be dereferenced" also on the period after "p1L"
p1L = p1L.equalsIgnoreCase(p1L);

I'm not sure what it means or how to go about fixing it.

I tried to redefine the scanners within the loop, as some classmates suggested but it doesn't seem to work or be the problem

```
Scanner tic = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner tac = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i = 0; wins || i == 9;i++) {
  tic = new Scanner(System.in);
  tac = new Scanner(System.in);

  table = line1+"/n"+A+"/n"+line2+"/n"+B+"/n"+line3+"/n"+C;

  System.out.println(table);//show table

  System.out.println("Enter Line A,B, or C for X (Player1)");
  p1L = tic.nextChar();
  p1L = p1L.equalsIgnoreCase(p1L);
  System.out.println ("Enter Row 1,2, or 3 for X (Player1)");
  p1R = tic.nextInt();
```

I expected the output to begin with the tic-tac-toe table, followed by request for my input. for example 
"Enter Line A, B, or C for X (Player1)"

Comment: While this won’t affect the compilation, you should not create two Scanner objects.  They will interfere with each other.  Create only one Scanner.

Comment: Let alone 22 of them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method called **nextChar()** in **Scanner** object. Did you mean **nextLine()**?

And I don't know what type of object in **p1L**. But what I can tell is that **equalsIgnoreCase()** is not a method of that what-ever-class.

Refer: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_user_input.asp
and 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Scanner tic = new Scanner(System.in); // use Standard Input for reading data (when the user writes to console)
Scanner tac = new Scanner(System.in); // delete because you have a scanner

for (int i = 0; wins || i == 9;i++) {
  tic = new Scanner(System.in); // delete because you have a Scanner
  tac = new Scanner(System.in); // delete because you have a Scanner

  table = line1+"/n"+A+"/n"+line2+"/n"+B+"/n"+line3+"/n"+C;

  System.out.println(table);//show table

  System.out.println("Enter Line A,B, or C for X (Player1)");
  p1L = tic.nextChar(); // delete, because method does not exist,
  p1L = p1L.equalsIgnoreCase(p1L); // delete, because method exist only data type String (text)
  p1L = tic.nextLine(); // read text
  p1L = p1L.toUpperCase() // make for "a" -> "A", for "A" -> "A"
  System.out.println ("Enter Row 1,2, or 3 for X (Player1)");
  p1R = tic.nextInt();
```